# C# convert string array output to double

Tags: c#, arrays, string, double, output

I am trying to take output from an array and convert to a double for use in a calculation.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
Console.WriteLine(product[1]);
double units = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Have been trying few other thing but getting no where; any easy solution?

Comment: What you expect this code to do? and what it does instead?

Comment: try 
double units = Convert.ToDouble(product[1]);
Console.WriteLine(units);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to write it to console and read it back.. simply:

```
var units = Convert.ToDouble(product[1]);
```

You might also consider using Double.TryParse() to check whether the value can be converted into a double and isn't a string of letters.

Comment: Thanks Dan and everyone - the above has worked for me

Answer (score 2):

your line could be throw exception if the user type some invalid double

```
double units = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

you should do this

```
double units ;
if (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out units )) {
    //units is not a double
}
else{
  //units is a double
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to convert the whole array to doubles, you could do this:

```
using System.Linq;

var doubleProduct = product.Select(p => double.Parse(p)).ToArray();
```

#### Edit

You can also use `Array.ConvertAll()` which is apparently more efficient (Thanks @PetSerAl for the tip). It also means you don't need Linq:

```
var doubleProduct = Array.ConvertAll(product, p => double.Parse(p));
```

Comment: You can use `Array.ConvertAll` witch more efficient for arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] values= { "-1,035.77219", "1AFF", "1e-35", 
                         "1,635,592,999,999,999,999,999,999", "-17.455", 
                         "190.34001", "1.29e325"};
      double result;

      foreach (string value in values)
      {
         try {
            result = Convert.ToDouble(value);
            Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, result);
         }   
         catch (FormatException) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a Double.", value);
         }               
         catch (OverflowException) {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is outside the range of a Double.", value);
         }
      }       
   }   
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       Converted '-1,035.77219' to -1035.77219.
//       Unable to convert '1AFF' to a Double.
//       Converted '1e-35' to 1E-35.
//       Converted '1,635,592,999,999,999,999,999,999' to 1.635593E+24.
//       Converted '-17.455' to -17.455.
//       Converted '190.34001' to 190.34001.
//       '1.29e325' is outside the range of a Double.
```

Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Console.WriteLine Method (String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Console.ReadLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please try folllowing:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] products= { "10.5","20.5","50.5"};
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDouble(product));
        }           
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cuezfc)